# How do I turn off geolocation when taking photos?

Tags: photos, geolocation

Is there a way to turn the geolocation feature for photos off? Is this per application or phone-wide?

*edit* I have a Droid X. I would like to have geolocation off even if my gps is on. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What phone do you have?  Most manufacturers that I know of have custom camera apps.  (It's per-application).

Comment: If GPS is off, does it still attempt to put in the Geo Location data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video seems to cover it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUV31pKOZcg&feature=player_embedded

To recap:

1. Open Camera app
2. Open Menu
3. Tap "Tags"
4. Uncheck Auto-Location tag
5. Done.

Answer (score 0):

For the camera in Jelly Bean it's a little easier:

1. Open the Camera app
2. Tap the "Circle" in the lower right to open the menu
3. Choose Settings
4. Make sure the toggle for "Store Location" is set to *Off*

I understand the camera for Jelly Bean 4.3 is a little different (it presents the options as an arc instead of a circle) but the steps should be the same.